# List Elements manipulation

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list

Suppose I have a list,

```
['1-2', '1-3', '2-1', '3-2', '3-3', '6-1', '5-1', '4-1', '8-3', '8-2', '7-1', '9-1']
```

I need to output the unique elements, suppose if 1-2 and 1-3 are there, I need to output only 1 of the instance and these should be in sorted order without a -.

Sample output :

```
1 2 
2 1
3 2
4 1
5 1
6 1
7 1
8 2
9 1
```

Comment: ['1 2','2 1', '3 2', '4 1', '5 1', '6 1', '7 1','8 2', '9 1'] In result list

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: answerlist = []

for item in anslist:
    answerset = set(anslist)
print answerset

answerlist = list(answerset)
answerlist.sort()


print "Sorting", answerlist

Comment: In the above code, I tried converting it to set and back to list and sorting it, but it just sorted it, but didnot remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['1-2', '1-3', '2-1', '3-2', '3-3', '6-1', '5-1', '4-1', '8-3', '8-2', '7-1', '9-1']
l.sort()
added = []
for line in l:
    itms = line.split("-")
    if itms[0] in added:
        continue
    added.append(itms[0])
    print("%s %s" % (itms[0], itms[1]))
```